# Apple Thunderbolt or HDMI for external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, hdmi, cpu, dvi

Is there anybody who can answer me this question?
I have a Macbook Pro Retina 15" quad i7 etc and I use some programs/applications wich need a lot of cpu and also the macbook heats up like hell.

I want to extend my display with a 23 or 27 IPS monitor.
Which is the best way, is it through HDMI or Thunderbolt to DVI or VGA adapter.
The main thing is that I use almost all the resources/performance to run those programs..so ...which of the two options does not affect my CPU/RAM and graphics performance because I don't have any left.

Comment: Both will affect your performance, as you're doubling the screen real-estate you need to draw to.

Comment: @Tetsujin Why don't you post this as an answer (with some more details maybe)? And actually it's 4x the screen real-estate (at least with the 27" model) :-)

Comment: but this means there is no possible way to connect an external monitor whitout cpu or performance loss...kind of sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding another monitor cannot be anything other than more resource-intensive - every pixel takes resources to drive it & draw to it.

The 15" Retina screen resolution is 2880 x 1800
A standard 27" screen is 2560 x 1440 - almost doubling the number of pixels you're asking the machine to draw.
A 27" Retina 5k screen is 5120 x 2880 - almost four times the screen area you already have.

To come closer to actually answering your question…
In order of personal preference, I would choose
Thunderbolt > DisplayPort
HDMI
DVI
I would avoid VGA entirely these days.

Comment: Welcome - I added a paragraph closer to actually answering your original question

Comment: understood. but, if i choose to connect my display via Thunderbolt, i have 3 options, thunderb. to HDMI, thunderb. to DVI and thunderb. to VGA.

Comment: to have a better overview, this is my Monitor.

Comment: http://www8.hp.com/de/de/products/monitors/product-detail.html?oid=5328978

Comment: it would help me a lot if you could tell me which setting is the best for this kind of monitor?

Comment: Here's the version of that monitor in English! http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/sales-landing/hp-pavilion-23xi-23-inch-diagonal-ips-led-backlit-monitor?jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001

Comment: Second-hand, I presume. I wouldn't spend that kind of money on a new screen with that spec these days, they sell new at about €75. As it's only a 1920 x 1080 screen anyway, it won't make much difference which way you connect it, I wouldn't think. BTW, a screen that size at only 1080p will look very odd next to a Retina screen which is smaller but with a much higher resolution

Comment: Thank You a lot. Have a nice day and greetings from Romania.

Answer (score 1):

I drive 4 displays with my late 2013 MBP: the built in screen, an Apple 27 via TB, an iMac 24 set to display mode (command F2 after plugging in to the MBP TB) and an Apple 20 inch DVI via an HDMI to DVI adapter. I can run video on all 4 at the same time with no stuttering. You may not loose as much performance as you think.